# Take row data from data table - apex class

Tags: datatable, apex-code, visualforce

I am having one grid (data table).
  In each row , I am having SAVE button to save the record.
  I want to write controller code for taking row data on SAVE button click.
  I am new for apex.
  Please guide me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Page

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!accountList}" var="a" >
<apex:column >
    <apex:column headerValue="Action">
        <apex:commandLink value="Save" action="{!save}" rerender="table" >
            <apex:param name="Id" value="{!a.Id}" />
        </apex:commandLink>
</apex:column>
</apex:dataTable>
```

Controller

```
List<accountwrapper> accountList = new List<accountwrapper>();

public class accountwrapper
{
    public Account acc{get; set;}
    public string id {get; set;}
    public accountwrapper(Account a,string id)
    {
        this.acc = a;
        this.id = id;
    }
}

public PageReference save()
{
    string accId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    for(accountwrapper accwrapper : accountList){
        if(accwrapper.id == accId)
            upsert accwrapper.acc;
    }
    return null;
}
```